# Can I access feature name in scenario hook?

Tags: cucumber

I'd want to get feature name in scenario hook. How can I get it?

What information besides scenario name and exception message is available in scenario hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the feature name by accessing the feature from the scenario object:

```
Before do |scenario|
    case scenario
        when Cucumber::Ast::Scenario
            p scenario.feature.title
        when Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow
            p scenario.scenario_outline.feature.title
    end
end
```

Note that you have to handle scenarios vs scenario outlines differently.

For other information that is available about the scenario, the best bet is to view the documentation - see http://rdoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/Ast/Scenario.